# Border style for Ionic select isn't working

Tags: ionic3

How can I override styling for alert wrapper in Ion select for border radius?

```
.alert-md .alert-wrapper {
    border-radius: 300px;
    max-width: 380px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 16px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 16px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
<ion-item no-lines style="border:2px solid #EC3237" class="item">
    <ion-label style="font-size:18px; color: black;">Age group:</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="age">
      <ion-option value="f" selected="true"></ion-option>
      <ion-option value="m">30</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot override alert wrapper style to ion-select if you want to add same style like alert wrapper then put your style in **.select-md**

```
.select-md {
    padding: 13px 8px 13px 16px;
    max-width: 380px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Comment: can i change alert wrapper style in default style file instead of overiding it

Comment: what do you want to do,just tell me briefly you want to change your select css or alert-wrapper css?